# mvvmcross 4 beta2 uwp unable to compile Universal windows 10

Tags: msbuild, mvvmcross, uwp

Keep getting following error when compiling UAP 10 project with mvvmcross 4.0 beta2:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets(223,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\bpatel.nuget\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries\4.0.0-beta2\lib\uap\Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP\Properties\Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.rd.xml" because it was not found.

Thanks in advance,
Binoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 4.0.0-beta3. See pull request: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1109

Comment: Unfortunatly is seems with NuGet 3, all external file needed to make mvvmcross working is not possible anymore. That make thinks more difficult. If I am wrong I will be happy to know how to make it working.

Comment: You can add those files manually. MvvmCross will still work with Nuget 3 if you do that.

Comment: Do you know if it exist a document that explain what file ne to be added, and where I can found them?

Comment: That is partially explained [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/nuspec/WCommonContent/_%20Windows%20Store%20UI.txt). The code you need for this is [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/4.0/nuspec/WCommonContent)